# JavaScript - how to create well-structured elements with appendChild?

Tags: javascript, html, css, appendchild

I'm trying to make a simple hangman game and I'm using JavaScript to generate a word, then map the letters and create and render an element for each, like so:

```
function createLetter(L) {
  const NEW_LETTER = document.createElement("span");
  const LETTER_DISPLAY = document.createElement("p");
  const LETTER_VAL = document.createTextNode(L);
  NEW_LETTER.classList.add("letter");
  LETTER_DISPLAY.classList.add("letter-display");
  LETTER_DISPLAY.appendChild(LETTER_VAL);
  NEW_LETTER.appendChild(LETTER_DISPLAY);
  console.log(document.getElementById("word"));
  renderLetter(NEW_LETTER);
}

function renderLetter(L) {
  document.getElementById("word").appendChild(L);
}
```

The result is fine, but the HTML span element(s) comes out as one line:

```
  <span class="letter"><p class="letter-display">R</p></span><span class="letter"><p class="letter-display">R</p></span>
```

But I need it to be like either of these two:

```
<div id="word">
  <span class="letter">
    <p class="letter-display"></p>
  </span>
  <span class="letter">
    <p class="letter-display">A</p>
  </span>
  <span class="letter">
    <p class="letter-display">T</p>
  </span>
                    // or
  <span class="letter"><p class="letter-display">H</p></span>
  <span class="letter"><p class="letter-display">I</p></span>
```

The reason being that when the spans are sat beside one another, there is no gap between the letters, but when they are on new lines in the markup, they have the correct spacing:

[Here's the CodePen. The two "R"s on the right are the wrong spacing.](https://codepen.io/fitfingers/pen/bzjLWW?editors=1011)

I know I can solve the problem with margin, I'm simply asking because I'd like to understand how I could structure newly-created elements correctly in future (although next time I think I would use React) :)

Comment: `<p>`s should *not* be children of `<span>`s

Comment: Oops! Had no idea; I always thought span was basically an inline div.

Comment: They are, but `<p>`s are block elements. Inline elements should only have inline children (block elements can have any children)

Comment: Ahh yeah that makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: If you want spaces between the elements, use `document.createTextNode(" ")`

Comment: You could also use CSS to add padding around the elements.

Comment: Yeah I have used margin to place it correctly, I just wondered if there was a certain trick to using appendChild to structure the markup the same way as I did manually or perhaps just to append children onto a new line (in the markup, not the actual page).

Comment: Swapping the elements as CertainPerformance suggests works - `<p class="letter"><span class="letter-display">A</span></p>` - that's how your HTML should look.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanations :)